# Lock a table in Sybase ASE 15.5

Tags: locking, sybase-ase

I would like to lock a table to only allow users to perform read operation in Sybase ASE 15.5, how can I do it? I have tried the below command, but seems there is some confusion. Any idea?

Session A: Perform below commands and after that try to perform insert operation. New records can still insert into locked table (but I think it is not commit the transaction yet). Can still select record from the locked table.

```
begin transaction
lock table testB in share mode
```

Session B: Cannot select data from the locked table.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at locking mechanism of table, there are three types of them - AllPages, Datapages and Datrows, you can read more about them at:

[Locking Mechanism in Sybase](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20021_1251/html/locking/locking7.htm)

If you alter locking of table, update/delete and select can take place together without any blocking on mentioned table.

Inside query, you can put noholdlock on a table or other options for other users to access/no access based on these options as mentioned in below link:

[Controlling Isolation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20021_1251/html/locking/locking88.htm)

In order to answer your question in detailed level, we need to have more clarity on question. Your question doesn't explain details of issue. I hope above helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want users to insert data to a table - remove the rights of insert/update/delete on this table.

Locking a table within transaction act differently, it depends on what kind of lock scheme it have etc etc.

Elaborate your scenario in detail.

Meantime check this http://infocenter-archive.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc33621_33620_33619_1250/html/ptallbk/X20061.htm